# Wso2 Scope Based Resources Access Control Implementation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, scopes

Wso2 API Manager v2.6.0

We are trying to set up scopes for few of the resources under an API.
Scope is created and mapped to the resource.

Generated the token for the Scope and while using that token for the resource, Getting below response:-

```
{
  "fault": {
    "code": 900900,
    "message": "Unclassified Authentication Failure",
    "description": "Error while accessing backend services for API key validation"
  }
}
```

And below errors in the gw errors log file:-

```
2020-08-03 15:03:43,726 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-4]  WARN ThriftKeyValidatorClient Login failed.. Authenticating again..
2020-08-03 15:03:43,756 [-] [pool-29-thread-2] ERROR TThreadPoolServer Error occurred during processing of message.
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException: Invalid tenant domain null
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityRuntimeException.error(IdentityRuntimeException.java:63)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityTenantUtil.getTenantId(IdentityTenantUtil.java:252)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.JDBCScopeValidator.getTenantId(JDBCScopeValidator.java:294)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.validators.JDBCScopeValidator.validateScope(JDBCScopeValidator.java:150)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler.validateScopes(DefaultKeyValidationHandler.java:180)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyValidationService.validateKey(APIKeyValidationService.java:188)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.thrift.APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.validateKey(APIKeyValidationServiceImpl.java:132)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:379)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Processor$validateKey.getResult(APIKeyValidationService.java:367)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-08-03 15:03:43,760 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-4] ERROR APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Unclassified Authentication Failure
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Error while accessing backend services for API key validation
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.thrift.ThriftAPIDataStore.getAPIKeyData(ThriftAPIDataStore.java:55)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.doGetKeyValidationInfo(APIKeyValidator.java:323)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIKeyValidator.getKeyValidationInfo(APIKeyValidator.java:255)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:206)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:325)
        Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.thrift.ThriftKeyValidatorClient.getAPIKeyData(ThriftKeyValidatorClient.java:94)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.thrift.ThriftAPIDataStore.getAPIKeyData(ThriftAPIDataStore.java:52)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Client.recv_validateKey(APIKeyValidationService.java:108)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.generated.thrift.APIKeyValidationService$Client.validateKey(APIKeyValidationService.java:83)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.thrift.ThriftKeyValidatorClient.getAPIKeyData(ThriftKeyValidatorClient.java:90)
        ... 25 more
```

Thrift Configuration in api-manager.xml is as below:-

```
 <APIKeyValidator>
        <!-- Server URL of the API key manager -->
        <ServerURL>https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>

        <!-- Admin username for API key manager. -->
        <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
        <!-- Admin password for API key manager. -->
        <Password>${admin.password}</Password>

        <KeyValidatorClientType>ThriftClient</KeyValidatorClientType>
        <ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>10000</ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>
        <!--ThriftClientPort>10397</ThriftClientPort-->

        <EnableThriftServer>true</EnableThriftServer>
        <ThriftServerHost>localhost</ThriftServerHost>
        <!--ThriftServerPort>10397</ThriftServerPort-->

        <ConnectionPool>
            <MaxIdle>100</MaxIdle>
            <InitIdleCapacity>50</InitIdleCapacity>
        </ConnectionPool>
        <KeyValidationHandlerClassName>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler</KeyValidationHandlerClassName>
 </APIKeyValidator>
```

Unable to get the scopes working with resources. Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a distributed setup? If so can you set the KeyValidatorClientType to WSClient and try this? Now it is recommended to use WSClient for any deployment.

Comment: It is a distributed setup. I will try and let you know about it. Thanks :)

Comment: I am having the same problem with a  Active-active all-in-one setup. Change to WSClient end the problem persists.